# Event binding angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to bind event with this "tmp", but this attaches also with previous existing button, why?

```
constructor(private renderer :Renderer ,private element : ElementRef){
        }
    private appender(){
        var tmp  = this.renderer.createElement(this.element.nativeElement,'button');
        this.renderer.listen(tmp, 'click', ( event:Event ) => console.log(event));
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean `this "tmp"`?

Comment: insufficient code, put as much code as possible to get help

Comment: "this" refers to the component in which it is written in angular 2.

Comment: "this" refers to the component in which it is written in angular 2 and function appender is called when a button clicks.

Comment: You should also give a bigger picture, and tell what you're trying to achieve. It seems you're creating a DOM element programmatically, which is, most of the time a bad idea. The DOM should be generated from the template of the component.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using `Renderer2` as below,

Injecting the Renderer2 service to the component

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2){}
```

Register an event listener using `listen` method

```
this.renderer.listen('body', 'click',this.calback)
```

Call back function will be executed when the event is triggered.

```
calback(event){
  console.log(event)
}
```

Note: Method definition for listen [refer docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#listen) for more information

```
listen(target: 'window'|'document'|'body'|any, eventName: string, callback: (event: any)
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Mx5yRr8uvDw1GExrxoLu?p=preview)**